# PGFPlots: problem in several graphs alignment

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subfloats

my issue is related with this previous one: [Problem with graphs alignment using pgfplots and subfig packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353143/problem-with-graphs-alignment-using-pgfplots-and-subfig-packages). I adopted the recommended commands `height` and `ymax`/`ymin`  to adjust the yaxis scale (and also to make its size standard) of three graphs. But apparently equal size doesn't mean correct adjustment. It's very subtle, but it seems that, from bottom-down, the y-axis is moving to the left (I took a ruler to compare). I would like to ask you what I'm missing. The code contains a template of brazillian norms for academic works, just justifying.

[image: sinusoidal graphs]

```
    \documentclass[
            % -- opções da classe memoir --
            12pt,
            openright,
            oneside,
            a4paper,
            % -- opções da classe abntex2 --
            chapter=TITLE,         
            section=TITLE,         
            subsection=Title,      
            % -- opções do pacote babel --
            english,                        
            french,                         
            spanish,                        
            portugues,                    
            %%%%%%%%%%%%
            sumario=tradicional             % título no formato tradicional
            ]{abntex2}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc,patterns,angles,quotes}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}    
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                    width=8cm,height=4cm,
                    ymax = 12, ymin = -12,
                    xmax = 5,
                    axis x line=middle,
                    axis y line=middle, 
                    axis line style={-stealth},
                    xlabel = {$t$},xlabel style={at={(1,0.5)}, anchor=west},ylabel style={at={(0,1)}, anchor=south},
                    ylabel = {$x$},
                    %xtick distance = 90,
                    ytick = \empty,
                    xtick={0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4},
                    xticklabels={ , , , ,$\tau$, , , , $2\tau$},
            ]
            \addplot[domain=0:4.5, 
                    samples=100, 
                    color=black,
                    thick,]
                {cos(deg(pi*x))};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            %Here ends the first plot
            \vskip 5pt
            %Here begins the second plot
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                    width=8cm,height=4cm,
                    ymax = 12, ymin = -12,
                    xmax = 5,
                    axis x line=middle,
                    axis y line=middle, 
                    axis line style={-stealth},
                    xlabel=$t$, xlabel style={at={(1,0.5)}, anchor=west},
                    ylabel=$v$, ylabel style={at={(0,1)}, anchor=south},
                    ytick=\empty,
                    xtick={0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4},
                    xticklabels={, , , , $\tau$, , , , $2\tau$},
            ]
            \addplot[domain=0:4.5, 
                    samples=100, 
                    color=black,
                    thick,]
                {-pi*sin(deg(pi*x))};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \vskip 5pt
            %Here begins the third plot
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                    width=8cm,height=4cm,
                    ymax = 12, ymin = -12,
                    xmax = 5,
                    axis x line=middle,
                    axis y line=middle, 
                    axis line style={-stealth},
                    xlabel=$t$,xlabel style={at={(1,0.5)}, anchor=west},
                    ylabel=$a$,ylabel style={at={(0,1)}, anchor=south},
                    ytick=\empty,
                    xtick={0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4},
                    xticklabels={, , , , $\tau$, , , , $2\tau$},
            ]
            \addplot[domain=0:4.5, 
                    samples=100, 
                    color=black,
                    thick,]
                {pi^2*cos(deg(pi*x))};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
```

PS: I shouldn't ask a second unrelated question, but is there a way to move the label to the bottom of every figure? The norms so demand.

Comment: Regarding the labels: you haven't shown us how you created them in the first place. There are multiple ways of adding such labels, but if you want to just modify what you already have, you need to show us what you have. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys! The `trim` idea to move every graphs slightly and the `commonstyle`  to adjust the letter size were the right points!
This time I managed to get rid of the `subfloat` environment. Now I'm using `subfigures` and here it goes:

```
        [![\documentclass\[\]{article}
        \usepackage\[T1\]{fontenc}
        \usepackage\[utf8\]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
        \usepackage{caption}        % new package
        \usepackage{subcaption}    % new package
        \begin{document}
        \begin{center}\small
        \begin{figure}\[!ht\]
        \pgfplotsset{commonaxisstyle/.style={
                width=8cm,height=4cm,
                ymax = 12, ymin = -12,
                xmax = 5,
                axis x line=middle,
                axis y line=middle,
                axis line style={-stealth},
                xlabel = {$t$},
                xlabel style={at={(1,0.5)}},
                ylabel style={at={(0,1)}, anchor=south,text width=1em,align=center},
                %xtick distance = 90,
                ytick = \empty,
                xtick={0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4},
                xticklabels={ , , , ,$\tau$, , , , $2\tau$},
                domain=0:4.5, samples=101,}
        \centering
        \tikzset{every picture/.style={trim left}}
        \begin{subfigure}\[b\]{\textwidth}
          \centering
          \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}\[commonaxisstyle, ylabel={$x$}\]
            \addplot\[thick\]
            {cos(deg(pi*x))};
            \end{axis}
          \end{tikzpicture}
          \label{position}
       \end{subfigure}
    
    \begin{subfigure}\[b\]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}\[commonaxisstyle, ylabel={$v$}\]
            \addplot\[thick\]
            {-pi*sin(deg(pi*x))};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \label{velocity}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \begin{subfigure}\[b\]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}\[commonaxisstyle, ylabel={$a$}\]
            \addplot\[thick\]
            {pi^2*cos(deg(pi*x))};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \label{acceleration}
    \end{subfigure}    
  \end{figure}
  \end{center}
  \end{document}
```

Thank you! Here's the result:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9pFt.png

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the different widths of your `ylabel`s, i.e. `x, v, a`.
Each `tikzpicture` will simply start at the leftmost position. The width of all your plots is not exactly the same!

If you move all your `ylabel`s slightly to the right, the plots will be aligned correctly:

```
ylabel style={at={(0.05,0.9)}
```

Another possibility is to put all plots inside one `tikzpicture` environment and then shift each axis where you need it:

```
\begin{axis}[yshift=-3.5cm, ...]
```

but I don't know if that would work nicely with your labels because I cannot recreate your document.

Comment: Instead of `yshift`, one could use the `groupplot` environment from the `groupplots` library.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a compilable, slightly more compact version of your code.
I added some `ylabel style` options to give a minimum width to the label, to make it independent of the actual letter. I also regrouped the common axis options so to clarify the code.

The small frames are here only to show the actual width of the modified label with this option

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc,patterns,angles,quotes}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{commonaxisstyle/.style={
    width=8cm,height=4cm,
    ymax = 12, ymin = -12,
    xmax = 5,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis line style={-stealth},
    xlabel = {$t$},
    xlabel style={at={(1,0.5)}},
    ylabel style={at={(0,1)}, anchor=south,draw=black,text width=1em,align=center},
    %xtick distance = 90,
    ytick = \empty,
    xtick={0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4},
    xticklabels={ , , , ,$\tau$, , , , $2\tau$},
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            commonaxisstyle,
            ylabel={$x$},
        ]
        \addplot[domain=0:4.5,
            samples=100,
            color=black,
            thick,]
        {cos(deg(pi*x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        commonaxisstyle,
        ylabel={$v$},
        ]
        \addplot[domain=0:4.5,
            samples=100,
            color=black,
            thick,]
        {-pi*sin(deg(pi*x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        commonaxisstyle,
        ylabel={$a$},
        ]
        \addplot[domain=0:4.5,
            samples=100,
            color=black,
            thick,]
        {pi^2*cos(deg(pi*x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- you use ancient version of the `pgfplots` package (version 1.9). Recent version is 1,17! I strongly encourage you to upgrade it.
- I suspect, that you like to have in line y-axis of diagrams, am I right? This can be achieved by adding option `trim left` to each `\tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass[
            % -- opções da classe memoir --
            12pt, openright, oneside, a4paper,
            % -- opções da classe abntex2 --
            chapter=TITLE,  section=TITLE, subsection=Title,
            % -- opções do pacote babel --
            english, french, spanish, portugues,
            %%%%%%%%%%%%
            sumario=tradicional             % título no formato tradicional
            ]{abntex2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}   % 1.9 is too ancient
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows,
                calc,
                patterns,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\pgfplotsset{
    width=8cm,height=4cm,
    ymax=15, ymin=-11,
    xmax=5,
    axis lines = middle,
    axis line style={-stealth},
    xlabel = {$t$},
    ylabel style={anchor=south},
    ytick = \empty,
    xtick={0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4},
    xticklabels={ , , , ,$\tau$, , , , $2\tau$},
%
    domain=0:4.5, samples=101,
            }
\tikzset{every picture/.style={trim left}} % <---
\centering
    \subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ylabel={$xxx$}]
\addplot[thick] {cos(deg(pi*x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
            }

    \subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ylabel={$v$}]
\addplot[thick] {-pi*sin(deg(pi*x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
            }

    \subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ylabel={$a$}]
\addplot[thick]     {pi^2*cos(deg(pi*x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
            }
\caption{My caption}
\label{fig:comparison}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note:

- For above MWE you need to have installed `subcaption` version 3.58 or newest.
- In MWE is used idea for common `pgfplotset` for all diagrams from [BambOo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544061/pgfplots-problem-in-several-graphs-alignment/544168#544168).